# How to make my WP8 app compatible for WP7.8

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am asking here because I'm a little bit confused. I have a working WP8 apps, with WP8 specific features such as speech recognition and custom tiles. I would like to make my app compatible for WP7.x

I know I have to remove speech recognition from my app to support WP7

1 - Where should I start ? Could I use the same project on Visual Studio 2013 or should I create another project on Visual Studio 2012 ?

2- Is it simpler to target only WP7.8 or can I do WP7.5 and WP7.8 in a same project ?

3 - I want to keep the use of async/await method, can I do that in WP7.8 or WP7.5?

Thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to create a new project targeting 7.1. WP7.x apps can run in WP8 devices, but not in the other way.
2. When createing the project, you target 7.1. If you have the latest SDK installed WP7.8 features will be available.
3. You can by adding [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) package from NuGet

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer.

1- so Should I use Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 ? 

2- So it is the same project either if I want to target 7.8 or 7.5 ? right ?

Answer (score 0):

"Could I use the same project on Visual Studio 2013 or should I create another project on Visual Studio 2012 ?"

You cannot target WP7 in VS 2013. You must use VS 2012 or 2010.

"Is it simpler to target only WP7.8 or can I do WP7.5 and WP7.8 in a same project ?"

You can target both in the same project. The main difference is just different tile sizes in 7.8 and if you want to support this you can use reflection to check. Otherwise there is no difference.

"I want to keep the use of async/await method, can I do that in WP7.8 or WP7.5? "

There are Nuget packages which support this.